# iOS internal proxy in app

Tags: objective-c, ios, proxy, offline-mode, cfnetwork

In one of our apps, we have to implement an online / offline feature. The caching is already done. What we have to do, however, is to implement a save way to prevent the app from opening a network connection. So my idea was, use CFNetwork to route every network call thru an internal proxy which checks the status of the app. If the app is allowed to go online it simply forwards the message. If not, it returns an http error.

My question is: Are there any open source proxies out there, that can handle this feature or do I have to implement the proxy all by myself?

Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing the caching / making the requests? Because `NSURLConnection` supports caching by default, and has a cache mode `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad` that will *only* load from the cache (and return nil if the resource you're requesting isn't available in the cache). If you're not using `NSURLConnection`, what are you using instead (since this will probably affect your solution)?